# Update java in mac for eclipse installation

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I want to install Eclipse in my  Mac (Yosemite OS Installed). But there is an error popup : [image: Error Popup]

I Check my java configuration and i have 1.7 instaled.

[image: Java installation]

I made the update in `System preference > Java`

And i know that i have the installation of JAva 8 in my computer because when i type in my terminal this command:

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
```

I have java 1.8

But in my Os use the version 1.7 and not 1.8 what i have to do?
And why it is so difficult to do that, why it is not enough to update via System > Preferences

Thanks for you Help!

Comment: Change path, etc. IMO it's a bad idea to have two installations at the same time.

Comment: SO what i have to do? I want to delete the 1.7 and just use the new!

Comment: No idea how to uninstall things on Mac. As far as I can remember it's not possible, you'll have to delete it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this via homebrew and it work for me:

```
 brew update
 brew cask install java
```

It is now installed in java_home like the version 1.7

[image: enter first version instaled here]

But until the first version is in use.

Now  You just have to export to JAVA_HOME variable with this command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*'`
```

And it work

Thanks!

Comment: I get the error: `Error: Unknown command: cask`

Answer (score 1):

Try this on a terminal window

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

you might get something like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home` (<-- that's mine, java 8)

Yours might point to Java 7. You can change `JAVA_HOME` to point to your Java 8 installation by doing

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java8-installation>
```

And then it should work.

(btw: your installation dir for Java 8 looks rather odd. you might want to re-install so that it is on a path that looks like mine above)

Comment: I'd start here. Java 7 build 60 is broken anyway. https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml

Answer (score 1):

The `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` Java is just the JRE, you need the full JDK to run Eclipse (and other Java applications) on a Mac.

So download and install the Java 8 JDK from the official [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install homebrew
   `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

   See [Homebrew homepage here](https://brew.sh/)
2. Install java using homebrew

   `a. brew update
   b. brew tap caskroom/cask
   c. brew install brew-cask
   d. brew cask install java`

   See full instructions at (tomysmile/brew-java-and-jenv.md)[https://gist.github.com/tomysmile/a9a7aee85ff73454bd57e198ad90e614]
3. Install [jenv](http://www.jenv.be/), a java environment manager
   `brew install jenv`
4. Add jenv to your path - see jenv page above
5. Add java path using jenv
   `jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/your-jdk-version/Contents/Home`
   Replace `your-jdk-version` with the version of jdk you have installed on your system
6. Restart eclipse and that's it